# qt_wrap_ui and uic commands

Tags: c++, qt

I'm currently designing a very simple gui using qt.

When I generate the header file of the interface from the interface.ui file, either using **uic** command line or **qt_wrap_ui**, it contains, among the others, the following include:

```
#include "../src/some_file.h"
```

Since I'm working with highly nested folders, I was wondering if there is a way to change this apparently-by-default behavior, defining custom includes, such as the following:

```
#include "nice_folder/far_from_build/here.h"
```

Thanks a lot,
T.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Qmake to do this all automatically?

Comment: Unfortunately because I cannot, I have to use other utilities.

Comment: You could just make sure compilation has the right -I include folder flag, so that the default #include works.

Comment: I already managed to do that, but personally this is not the solution I would love to adopt.